# What is the role of "but" in this context?

Tags: grammar

> For the electronics industry, the television is an important but increasingly difficult product to sell.

I've already searched over the internet about all the meanings the conjunction but can have in a sentence, but I don't understand its meaning in this very context. I have read a text saying that the conjunction "but" can be used to add informations to a first sentence. Can you guys give me a hand and help me understand?

Comment: It's just a conjunction. _But_ means "and". Try substituting _and_ to see: _television is an important **and** increasingly difficult product to sell_. The only difference between _but_ and _and_ is that _but_ implies some surprise on the part of the speaker -- something is not going as expected. What that might be is determined by context.

Comment: That is a large and angry bear. That is a large but timid moose.

Comment: I was suspecting that it would be like you just said. It makes pretty sense to substitute but for and in this context. I just needed someone to confirm it to me, and you did it so. I appreciate your help. Thank you John Lawler and Edwin Ashworth!

Comment: I always think of *but* as used here as “while at the same time”

Comment: In this context, one could construe that the use of "but" attempts to contrast positive and negative ideas about selling televisions. The idea of selling the television is important for the success of the electronics industry, which seems to be a positive idea in this context. The television being increasingly difficult to sell implies a negative idea due to the nature of challenge and failure.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of *but* is a conjunction, meaning "on the contrary; in contrast" (New Oxford American Dictionary). It is the same as *and*, but emphasizes contrast. You can replace it with "however" or "yet".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's just a conjunction. *But* means "and". Try substituting *and* to see: *television is an important **and** increasingly difficult product to sell*. The only difference between *but* and *and* is that *but* implies some surprise on the part of the speaker -- something is not going as expected. What that might be is determined by context.

Answer (score -1):

'For the electronics industry, the television is an important but increasingly difficult product to sell." Before elaborating on the grammatical function of 'but' in this sentence, it is neccessary to correct a prior error which inevitably affects it. "For the electronics industry, the television is : 1) an important -product- 2)increasingly difficult product to sell. While it's okay to say "the television is an important product for the electronics industry", to say "the television is an increasingly difficult product to sell for the electronics industry", on the other hand, doesn't make sense. 'But' splits the noun "Product" into the above-two attributes. However, a confusing double-reference to 'the electronic industry" was made as well. References stick to 'for' like a magnet. Although the two ideas are clearly highlighted, the sentence to flow needs to be entirely rewritten I'm afraid. Also, 'but'+'and'= yet. I propose: Television is an important product of the Electronic industry YET increasingly difficult to sell ( We haven't have had any ' easy ' sales on television yet).