# What is this literary device called?

Tags: literary-device

When we use a conjunction such as "but" or "yet" to dramatically interrupt the rhythm of a sentence.

What's this literary device called?

Comment: They're called _contrastives_.

Comment: An example would be beneficial to the question, yet remains unwritten therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the role of "but" in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384178/what-is-the-role-of-but-in-this-context)

Comment: Perhaps rhetorical devices is the area  here: contrast. There are others that might fit, as well.

Comment: I'd call it "butting in".

Answer (score 2):

This is called the Oppositional/Contrastive relationship:

> One way to look at the oppositional or contrastive relationship is as the opposite of the additive relationship. In other words, the speaker, having mentioned one thing, wants to go on to talk about something else which contrasts with and is often in opposition to the first thing.
>   Conjunctions and the Oppositional or Contrastitive Relationship
>
> The following conjunctions are used to express the oppositional/contrastive relationship:
>
> - but
> - although
> - even
> - though
> - though
> - whereas
> - while
> - either . . . or

From: [Rochester Institute of Technology - SEA](https://www.ntid.rit.edu/sea/processes/relationships/grammatical/logical/oppositionalcontrastive)

Answer (score -1):

I've just found out that it's called "disjunction"

Comment: How about a link to where you found that?